# How to group rewards from delegation services on multiple KT1 accounts per cycle?

Tags: tzscan, delegating

I have a tz1 address and created multiple KT1 addresses to be able to delegate my XTZ to multiple delegation services. I can query the tzscan.io API to automatically get the rewards I receive via `/operations` and filter out only transactions with funds sent to my KT1 address.

But since every delegation service has their own payout schedule I am unable to successfully group the rewards per cycle. Is this even possible to group them per cycle? Currently I group the results per day. But this is a complete mess, because of the change of day over midnight.

The result should be how many XTZ a tz1 address received per cycle, regardless of how many KT1 address are associated and regardless of when each KT1 address started delegating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should help you (Example TzScan API):

https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/KT1BNVf6f359fNbokCKMXuKNmpzUy3Nwugyj

Just put in one of the KT1 adresses and it will show you the total rewards per cycle, for the associated tz1 address.

Comment: This adds a little more complexity, but I guess I could work with this, if there isn't an easier solution. thank you.

Comment: If the grouping per KT1 address should still be possible, then using `/balance_history` and subtracting the amount from the previous cycle might be useful.